# Make Android Lifecycle Observer receiver non nullable in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I have `Result` wrapper that wraps data comes from backend

```
data class Result<T>(val success: Boolean, val result: T?, val message: String?)
```

Idea of this, check `success` instead of result being null or not valid and get formatted message for UI error reporting. But when trying to use this with android lifestyle components, specifically in `Observer` I have to check for null.

[image]

How can I avoid this null check? This happens because of

```
void onChanged(@Nullable T t);
```

in `Observer`. I've tried to extend this but it seem to require more custom wrapper classes. Do we have a solution for avoid null check here.

Comment: I think its mostly because the output(Result<Location>?) can be either success or Null. Therefore it is asking you to add a safe operator check to avoid that. So I think it should be `it?.success` or you can do a `let` operator on the result.

Comment: Your right from one perspective, but since we handling the updates of `MutableLiveData` we can make sure that `null` is not posted as result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a framework bug that argument is annotated as @Nullable. Fixed in androix.lifecycle 2.0.0-beta01.

Answer (score 2):

> Updated answer from *@Andrei Vinogradov's answer*

Until you upgrade to **2.0.0-beta01**, you can try this solution. Use standard function **let** from Kotlin library :

```
it?.let{ result ->
    if(result.success){
    // Rest of your code ..
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to have no code at all to check nulls. But this works otherwise, thanks